# undergoes oxidation reactions to other compounds that are eliminated by the body

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'm reading chemistry book and have found this sentence which I could not understand even though I know the meaning of oxidize which means to combine with oxygen and the meaning of eliminate which means completely get rid of something according to Longman Dictionary.
The thing I'm wondering about is  ( alcohol undergoes oxidation to other compounds that are eliminated by the body. ). so there are compounds which our body eliminate and alcohol  is one of them and our body eliminate it by oxidation . is that right

This is the text:

> Sarah determines that the victim was
>   poisoned when she ingested ethylene glycol placed in an
>   alcoholic beverage. Since the initial symptoms of ethylene
>   glycol poisoning are similar to being intoxicated, the victim
>   was unaware of the poisoning.
>   **The alcohol in beverages undergoes oxidation
>   reactions to other compounds that are eliminated
>   by the body. When ethylene glycol is oxidized,**
>   the products can cause renal failure and may be
>   toxic to the body.

Comment: That's poorly written.  It appears to mean that the oxidation reactions convert the alcohol to other compounds, and those compounds, rather than the alcohol, are what is eliminated.

Comment: "oxidation reactions resulting in other compounds" or "forming other compounds" or even "to form other compounds" would be better. It's possible that the single word *form* was accidentally omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the gist of it: ethanol (alcohol) undergoes several enzyme-triggered metabolic steps that turns it into only slightly toxic substances (e.g. acetaldehyde, mostly responsible for hangover) that are soon eliminated. Whereas the oxidation of ethylene glycol produces different catabolites, one of them being the oxalic acid particularly toxic to the kidneys.